# CCPhysics collision callback issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, collision-detection, cocos2d-x-2.x

I have added two objects, each with there own physicsBody. The first one has a collision type `Player` and the second `Enemy`. Strangely, the callback isn't working when I set it to:

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair Player:(CCNode *)nodeA Enemy:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    return true;
}
```

but when I set the method to this:

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair Player:(CCNode *)nodeA wildcard:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    return true;
}
```

it works, but obviously I don't want it to be detecting collisions on every object that they player comes into contact with, I just want the collision with the Enemy. To make this more puzzling, I thought that the name might be wrong on the collision type for the Enemy. With the working method listed above I added this:

```
NSString* nodeAType = [nodeA.physicsBody collisionType];
NSString* nodeBType = [nodeB.physicsBody collisionType];
```

And sure enough the outputs were `Player` and `Enemy`.

The both objects **are** set as a sensor and **not** set as static (collision properties).

Comment: are they (Enemy and Player) by any chance in the same collision group?

Comment: @AbhineetPrasad nope. They also arn't in any categories or masks. I tried putting them in those but that didn't do anything either.